# what I am supposed to do on questions like this?

Tags: discussion

I have seen a question in Ask Ubuntu :[Some Bash questions for a newbie](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356334/some-bash-questions-for-a-newbie/356338#356334)

Here that question is a BASH script which is too long and with many queries were posted by the OP.

here my point is , according to AU rules one question per one post.

But OP asking too many &  all the questions about the same question/post only.

do we have to suggest him that maintain one question per one post or keep it like that ?

Comment: I see that questions 2-4 are about general programming language and are not strict Ubuntu exclusive. I would close it for being too broad.

Answer (score 6):

"Some bash questions for a newbie" isn't a question. :)

I would ask them to trim it down to be "How do I indent code in gedit?" which is the only part that is salvageable here, the rest can go on stackoverflow.

That title is a mess, I don't get how it got 2 upvotes and no one fixed it. Here's a quick search of questions with question in the title that can be fixed up if someone's looking for a nice low hanging fruit:

- https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion

Comment: Vote: To be honest I gave one up vote.

Comment: The question content is fine, it just needs to be fixed to make sense.